# getElementsByTagName causing issues with IE

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

We have [this website](http://www.mediwales.com/pictureofhealth) that contains a Google map plotting multiple markers. This works fine on all browsers except IE.

The error it's giving is:

> Unable to get value of the property 'getElementsByTagName': object is
>   null or undefined line 112 character 9.

This is the line of code that's causing the issue in IE:

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

The XML looks fine but just can't work out the problem. Can anyone see whats wrong?

Comment: @WayneWhitty All versions of IE.

Comment: The error says the problem is with `xml.documentElement` being undefined. There's nothing wrong with `.getElementsByTagName`, but it'll only work if you call it on a valid DOM object. You need to find out why `xml.documentElement` is undefined; that's the key here; `getElementsByTagName` is a red herring; you'd have the same problem if you tried to do anything to `xml.documentElement`.

Comment: @Spudley The xml data is displaying fine in IE and all other browsers, not sure how to check this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

To:

```
    var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

And it worked across all browsers, I can't explain why!